# How to update shared value after async operation?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

```
const [action, setAction] = useState(true);
const sharedVal = useSharedValue(action ? 10 : 20)
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setAction(false)
    }, 2000)
}, [])
```

In the above code, the value of `shareVal` doesn't change the value of `action` changes. What is the best way to update value of `sharedVal` after the `timeout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll have to run a side effect when `action` changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  
  sharedVal.value = action ? 10 : 20;

  // this will run when action is updated 
}, [action]);
```

or you can just do `sharedVal.value = someValue` wherever you want.

[documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/useSharedValue/)

> (...) The reference is an object with `.value` property, that can be accessed and modified from worklets, but also **updated directly from the main JS thread.**

Comment: This is definitely how it should be done, but tbh I have a lot of inconsistencies in the updates with this method

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function Example() {
  const [action, setAction] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function useSharedValue(number) {
      const response = await fetch(....);
      const json = await response.json();
      setAction(true); // reset state here
    }

    useSharedValue(action ? 10 : 20);
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a code similar to yours. UseEffect is called every time there is a change in the alert variable, as you can see in my code bellow. If the second argument is empty [], useEffect will only be executed once when the page is loaded. As you want to call every time there is a change in the value of the action variable, just place it inside [].

```
    useEffect(() => {
       if (alert != '') setTimeout(() => { setAlert('') }, 4000);
    }, [alert]);
```